# Automatic code markup

Tags: wordpress, syntax-highlighting, markup

Is there a tool (similar to the markup here on StackOverflow) that transforms code (based on syntax and keywords) into markup'ed code? In other words, take a blot of code and **add the appropriate tags and styles** to have it show all pretty in colour (and indented maybe)?

Specifically, I'd like something that's language specific (or language aware) for at least C# and SQL. It can be a **plugin** to WordPress or just a **formatter** that I could post my code into and then copy paste to WordPress (or elsewhere. Portability is nice).

Comment: Close vote? Off topic? Seriously? It's not wordpress specific. It's about code, it's about a software tool *for software*. How is this not software related?

Comment: And ironically 3 years later it has become off topic, because it's a recommendation for an external tool. sigh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I, personally, like this script: http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/

Answer (score 2):

Vim is a remarkably good tool for this.  You don't have to use it as an editor (although every serous developer should consider doing just that--but I digress), you can use it as a pure syntax-aware code-to-html processor.

For example take this Python3 script (syntax coloring is by *StackOverflow* in this listing):

```
'Get geocode data from Google'

# See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding

import urllib, urllib2
import json

params = {'address': "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA",
          'sensor': 'false'}

base_url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json'
url = base_url + '?' + urllib.urlencode(params)

reply = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(url).read() )
print json.dumps(reply, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

Using *Vim* color scheme *Light* this method produces:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>~/Projects/google/geocoding.py.html</title>
<meta name="Generator" content="Vim/7.3">
<meta name="plugin-version" content="vim7.3_v10">
<meta name="syntax" content="python">
<meta name="settings" content="use_css,expand_tabs">
<style type="text/css">
<!--
pre { font-family: monospace; color: #000000; background-color: #c7c7c7; }
body { font-family: monospace; color: #000000; background-color: #c7c7c7; }
.Constant { color: #bd00bd; }
.Normal { color: #000000; background-color: #c7c7c7; }
.Statement { color: #191970; font-weight: bold; }
.Comment { color: #005500; }
.String { color: #8b4500; }
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
<span class="String">'Get geocode data from Google'</span>

<span class="Comment"># See <a href="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding">https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding</a></span>

<span class="Statement">import</span> urllib, urllib2
<span class="Statement">import</span> json

params = {<span class="String">'address'</span>: <span class="String">&quot;1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA&quot;</span>,
          <span class="String">'sensor'</span>: <span class="String">'false'</span>}

base_url = <span class="String">'<a href="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json">http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json</a>'</span>
url = base_url + <span class="String">'?'</span> + urllib<span class="Normal">.</span>urlencode(params)

reply = json<span class="Normal">.</span>loads(urllib2<span class="Normal">.</span>urlopen(url)<span class="Normal">.</span>read() )
print json<span class="Normal">.</span>dumps(reply, sort_keys=<span class="Statement">True</span>, indent=<span class="Constant">4</span>, separators=(<span class="String">','</span>, <span class="String">': '</span>))

</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that each syntax element is given a color in the CSS style section, which you can tweak in the html itself if you don't want to fiddle with *Vim* color schemes.

Here's what you'll see in your browser.  I've clipped this as an image to avoid color changes from *StackOverflow*:

[image: HTML syntax highlighting]

Here's how to do it:

1. Install a Vim gui.  The official [*Vim* download page](http://www.vim.org/download.php) will get you started.  If you can't use a gui, hope is not lost, I'll comment about that case below.
2. Choose the syntax coloring you want.  I use [this page](https://code.google.com/p/vimcolorschemetest/) to choose and download color schemes.  You put the color scheme files in your `~/.vim/colors` directory, or for Windows in `%USERPROPFILE%/vimfiles/colors`.
3. Start *Vim*.
4. Load the source code for which you want syntax-colored markup.  You do this with the command `:e <file path>` where `<file path>` is the location of the source file.  *Vim* gui's will also provide menu commands to open a file, you might prefer to do it that way so you can browse you file system.
5. Load your color scheme. Type `:color <name>` where `<name>` is the color scheme you saved in step 2, without the `.vim` extension.  For example, I use `:color synic` to load the color scheme in `~/.vim/colors/synic.vim`.  (In *Vim*, the ':' puts you into "command mode".  When you enter a command and press `<return>` you are back in what is called "normal mode".)
6. Tell *Vim* to generate the html using the command `:TOhtml`.  A new window will open up and you'll see the html markup.  Be sure to use the right capitalization when executing _Vim_commands.
7. Your cursor should be in the new window with the markup.  Save this using the gui's file menu, or enter the command `:w <file path>`

Optionally, if you want line numbers to display in the generated HTML, use the command `:set number` before `:TOhtml`.

If you don't see the syntax coloring show up after you set your color scheme, try the command `:syntax on`.  If you're doing syntax coloring for a language or text format that vim doesn't recognize you can probably find syntax files for that language on the web.  Details of how to install syntax files are beyond what I want to write about here, but your favorite search engine has plenty on the topic.  Try a search such as `vim <mylang> syntax`.  To see what language *Vim* thinks you have, use the command ":set ft?".

If, like me, you prefer to use the terminal form of `Vim`, there's a little more to consider.  You can not create colors that the terminal doesn't support.  Most terminal apps provide either 2, 16 or 256 colors.  Get *Vim* to output in 256 colors (if it doesn't already) using the instructions [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim).  Not all color schemes work well on terminals out of the box, but instructions on [this page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_GUI_color_settings_in_a_terminal) help substantially, although they are written with a more experienced *Vim* user in mind.  It's a good idea to run the *Vim* tutorial (`:help tutorial`) if you have to do more than I outline in my steps above.